# apache rewrite with proxy flag doesn't work with similar name

Tags: regex, apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, mod-proxy

I have a `/my-page.html` and `/hello/my-page.php` in my site, i have to get the content from my-page.php when calling my-page.html.

I wrote something the following, this is getting error.

```
RewriteRule "my-page.html" "/hello/my-page.php" [P]
```

But it will work when I change the name.

```
RewriteRule "my-somethingelse" "/hello/my-page.php" [P]
```

any idea how can i use the same name?

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to use `P` (proxy) flag here. You may just use `L`.

Also it seems you have option `MultiViews` enabled that you can just disable using this line at the top of your .htaccess:

```
Options -MultiViews
```

And rule:

```
RewriteRule ^/?my-page\.html$ /hello/my-page.php [L,NC]
```

Comment: No, I want to continue the next rules, then only it delivers the exact data. Thats why I use proxy

Comment: `L` does not stop further rules processing. Please test and see if that works.

Comment: And if you have `mod_proxy` setup then feel free to use `RewriteRule ^/?my-page\.html$ /hello/my-page.php [P,NC]` as well.

Comment: sorry not working :( getting 404 it will working only when i change the first name to something diffrent than second part

Comment: Can you post your full .htaccess in question